# Filtering in mysql with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `Products` and `Product_Data`. I want to store the `product` data separate from the `products` because `products` can have dynamic `properties` and therefore I did not want to put all the `products`' data in the `Products` table.

##### Product table

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| description | text | NO |  | NULL |  |
| price_currency | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| price_amount | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

##### Product data table

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| product_id | bigint unsigned | NO |  | NULL |  |
| attribute | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| value | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

I want to get all `products` that have both values: `Black` and `Man`. I tried running the following query, but it returns all `products with the attribute` Black`and`Man`.

```sql
SELECT product_id FROM product_data WHERE value IN ("black", "man");
```

I'm using [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) and [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent). The behavior described above, also reflects the result when I run the following code:

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('properties', function ($query) use ($searchValues) {
    $query->whereIn('value', $searchValues);
})
    ->paginate(25);
```

The code above returns all `products` that have `black` or `man`.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why is your `price_amount` a `varchar(255)`? Some numeric type would be a better fit... Or do you expect to accept values like `'banana'` as price?

Comment: @stickybit This is not a production ready application. I'm working out the details before refactoring. Also, the external api im using is unreliable at times, data changes and sometimes the data is indeed 'banana'. I'd rather have it collect wrong data at this stage, then not collecting data at all due to a Type issue. Also, I do not see how this comment helps in any way..

Comment: "I do not see how this comment helps in any way" -- It helps by making you aware of the usage of a wrong type if you weren't already. It has got nothing to do with the query though. I should have marked it as a side note to be clear. Those are acceptable here in comments.

Comment: The problem is that you put another layer of complexity in your query because of your dynamic attributes. I assume you could do some count operations and return only products where the black count > 0 and where the man count is > 0. But you will probably need some Raw operations for that.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having the same challenge, this is how I solved it:

```sql
SELECT product_id
FROM product_data
WHERE value IN ('black', 'man')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) >= 2;
```

This query filters all records having more than 2 hits. This query returns the list of `product_id`.